# Transposing a dataframe and using the first column as an index

Tags: r, transpose, melt

I have a dataframe that is structured like below, where A/B/C/D are different treatment methods:

```
input <- read.table(text="
filename wavelength  A    B    C    D
file1      w1        NA   NA   1   2
file1      w2        NA   NA   3   2
file1      w3        NA   NA   6   2
file2      w1        3    4    NA   NA
file2      w2        4    8    NA   NA
file2      w3        6    1    NA   NA", header=TRUE)
```

And I would like for it to be transposed so that wavelength is the header and treatments are rows with the filenames duplicated each time:

```
desired <- read.table(text="
filename Method   w1    w2   w3 
 file1      C     1    3     6
 file1      D     2    2     2
 file2      A     3    4     6 
 file2      B     4    8     1", header=TRUE)
```

I've tried `melt/cast` from `reshape2`, `melt` from the `data.table` package, `gather/spread`, `t` - everything I can think of. The actual data frame in the end will be about 500 rows by 3500 columns - so I would prefer not to call out any specific column or method names. My issue seems mainly to be that I can't call all method columns under one value and use it to melt:

```
colMethods <- myData[, 2:length(myData)]
```

A lot of times I don't get an error, but the dataframe R returns is just a list of wavelengths and a column that says 'wavelength'. How would any of you approach this? Thanks!

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks! Works great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df <- structure(list(filename = c("file1", "file1", "file1", "file2", 
"file2", "file2"), wavelength = c("w1", "w2", "w3", "w1", "w2", 
"w3"), A = c(NA, NA, NA, 3L, 4L, 6L), B = c(NA, NA, NA, 4L, 8L, 
1L), C = c(1L, 3L, 6L, NA, NA, NA), D = c(2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, 
NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Code:

```
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(1,2)) %>% filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = wavelength,values_from = value)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  filename name     w1    w2    w3
  <chr>    <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1 file1    C         1     3     6
2 file1    D         2     2     2
3 file2    A         3     4     6
4 file2    B         4     8     1
```

Comment: @Mulligan Great it helped! If you think this answer was helpful, you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of the answer :)

Comment: I know - there's a time limit to accept after an answer was posted

Answer (score 1):

Here is `data.table` alternative using `melt` and `dcast` :

```
library(data.table)

dcast(melt(setDT(input), id.vars = 1:2, na.rm = TRUE), 
          variable+filename~wavelength, value.var = 'value')

#   variable filename w1 w2 w3
#1:        A    file2  3  4  6
#2:        B    file2  4  8  1
#3:        C    file1  1  3  6
#4:        D    file1  2  2  2
```